# power bi import data taking forever

Tags: powerbi, loading

I usually work with power bi and all go well on my computer. Yesturday I downloaded it on a virtual machine itself on a Windows server 2019 machine that I connect on using "distant desktop" or whatever you call it to create a dashboard to visualize some data.

**The problem I'm having is that it is taking forever (over 10 hours by now) on the " creating connexions in model".**

Image is in french but it is pretty usual content:

[image]

precisions:

- I already have optimized the data, and can not reshape the tables more,
- The only big table (>100 rows) have a count of around 800k rows,
- I do have internet and can ping whatever I want,

Any idea where it can come from? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found my problem this morning while hanging in the options of the virtual machine.

I had only 1 virtual processor that was always used by other applications and so powerBi could not get nearly as much processing power as needed.

I just changed it and it loaded in seconds...

Conclusion: powerBi speed is based on your processing power, so when working on it, close as much windows as possible on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. Import of a local Excel sheet (1 tab, 2 cols, 30 rows) did not complete after 30 minutes using only one processor.

Upgrading the VM to more than one processor solved the issue.